# Set an EditText layoutDirection to ltr and gravity to center

Tags: android, android-edittext

My application is in a RTL language. I have an edit text that accepts number, so I need to set its layoutDirection to ltr to prevent it from being rtl. But the problem is that `android:gravity="center"` doesn't work this way and text is shown from left instead of center. How can I set EditText gravity to center while its layoutDirection is ltr?

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:background="@null"
     android:ems="10"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:layoutDirection="ltr"
     android:maxLength="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `android:textAlignment`, not `android:gravity`.

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I need the text to be in the middle of EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Use this , I hope this will help you.

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:maxLength="2"
                />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It has no difference with my own code!

Comment: use this in gravity:-
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

Comment: it doesn't work. sorry. as soon as I remove `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` it becomes okey

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` instead of `android:gravity` If your are using parent layout as LinearLayout